# How to check if a file has downloaded successfully?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

My page has a link that on clicking will download a file. I just need to check if the file has been downloaded and of the correct extension.

Comment: you can't, really. at most you can confirm that the entire file was sent out on the wire, but there's no practical way to confirm that the file was actually received by the user.

Comment: you can have to user "upload" it to JS using an <input type=file>, and from there you can check file name, even run a CRC/MD5 if you want. but why?

Answer (score 0):

For checking download with Chrome browser

The set up you can go for is as per the following

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26127745/511069

As suggested here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27031924/511069

you can create a function waitFileExists(fileAbsPath) and performs your expectations after the file is completely downloaded

Answer (score 0):

```
var downloadfile = path.join(__dirname,'\\dash-e2e-tests\\resources\\files-cabin\\download-files');

capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        prefs: {
            download: {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'directory_upgrade': true,
                'default_directory': downloadfile
            }
        }
    }

},
```

Use tabove code under cof.js file and once test case is done verify the file availability under given location.