# Download a file protractor test case

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am writting a protractor test case to download a file which can be of any type.

- Scenario: Download a file
- Step 1: Click on the Download Link
- Step 2: Check whether the file is downloaded or not

How do i check if the file is downloaded correctly or not?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was able to achieve download testing with Chrome.

1. Follow this config setup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26127745/511069
2. Create a `function waitFileExists(fileAbsPath)` and performs your expectations after the file is completely downloaded: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27031924/511069

Comment: hi @Leo Gallucci , i changed something to download excel and pdf. It worked for exporting excel file but falsed with pdf. I think "application/pdf" is not enough to set download automatically pdf file. What can I do ?

Comment: @AquariusPotter You need to add the content disposition header for that, see  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Sample code for an Angular/TypeScript project: https://gist.github.com/tw3/ef2858f3fe4d224e02eb9ff5dbca2aba

Comment: Thank you! You saved me hours of investigating.