# Can't stop Protractor from displaying file download prompt

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

#### Problem

I'm testing downloading a file, but when I trigger the download, the "Save as..." prompt appears.
I saw a solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935696/protractor-e2e-test-case-for-downloading-pdf-file) but it doesn't seem to work for me.

#### Config

My protractor config file looks like this (coffeescript):

```
exports.config =
  capabilities:
    browserName: "chrome"
    shardTestFiles: true
    maxInstances: 2
    chromeOptions:
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser']
      prefs:
        download:
          prompt_for_download: false
          default_directory: '/'
          default_content_settings:
            popups: 0
```

#### More

On `chromeOptions.pref` [webdriver docs](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) states:

> See the 'Preferences' file in Chrome's user data directory for examples.

I can't actually see `default_directory` in my own *Chrome preferences* file.

```
"download": {
  "directory_upgrade": true,
  "prompt_for_download": false
},
```

#### System

- Protractor: Version 1.5.0 (pretty new)
- Node: 0.10.28, 0.11.8 and 0.11.14

Comment: Have you tried to change the `default_directory` setting to a, for example, absolute path to an existing directory?

Comment: That worked, make it an answer and I'll tick it off

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provide an *absolute path to an existing directory* in `default_directory` chrome preference.

Comment: If I read this question/answer 6 hours ago it would have been a way much easier day for me :D

Comment: Is there any way not to use the `absolutePath`? If I try to you the `relative` the `popups` option does not work! thanks for this solution

Comment: I had the same problem @BrunoSoko and I solved it using this `'default_directory': process.cwd() + '/your/relative/path/'`

Answer (score 1):

For me, the Save As prompt was appearing when I mentioned a slash at last in the path for example: `A:\Proj\Downloads\` & didn't see any prompt when mentioned without a slash at the end of the path i.e `A:\Proj\Downloads`