# Setting chromedriver preferences on protractor tests

Tags: javascript, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to find a solution to download files during my tests, i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935696/protractor-e2e-test-case-for-downloading-pdf-file) question that lead me to preferences file in chrome folder.

Apparently, there are no info about shutting the prompt for download or/and setting a default folder. Does anyone knows how i can do this?

Here's what i tried:

```
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {

            prefs: {
                'downloads': {
                    'prompt_for_download': false,
                    'default_directory': '/downloads/'
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are doing it correctly, except you need to:

- specify an absolute path to the "downloads" directory
- add `directory_upgrade` option

Example:

```
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {

            prefs: {
                download: {
                    'prompt_for_download': false,
                    'directory_upgrade': true,
                    'default_directory': '/absolute/path/here'
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

See also: [Can't stop Protractor from displaying file download prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785731/cant-stop-protractor-from-displaying-file-download-prompt)

Comment: Got it, the key was the absolute path instead a relative path. PS: it is **download** instead **downloads**.

Comment: Obviously this won't work for another comuputer right? any idea on how to do it relative?

Comment: To make it work with a relative path one can use: `'default_directory': process.cwd() + '/relative/path/'`.