# Protractor - Jasmine - Download file to a relative path

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I've read and follow the below questions here and its comments/answers:

> #### [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785731/cant-stop-protractor-from-displaying-file-download-prompt)
>
> #### [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868730/prompt-for-download-is-still-appearing-after-setting-false-in-prefs)
>
> #### [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922587/setting-chromedriver-preferences-on-protractor-tests)

But could not find a way not to use `absolutePath`, since I need to have this tests run on another machine, so, I need to be relative to the project no the other folder outside of it. how can I accomplish that?

Comment: This topic will surely help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922587/setting-chromedriver-preferences-on-protractor-tests

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained in the questions you have quoted, You can control where the file downloads using the below option

```
'chromeOptions': {
       prefs: {
        download: {
          'prompt_for_download': false,
          'default_directory': <<absolutePath>>
        }
      }
    }
```

Coming to your question on how to accomplish this when running on different machines, the answer is - Generate absolute Path from relative path and pass it onto Chrome Options.

```
var path = require('path');
var downloadsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './downloads');
................
'chromeOptions': {
           prefs: {
            download: {
              'prompt_for_download': false,
              'default_directory': downloadsPath
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! this resolved the issue that I was having, plus other, because I didn't mention, that I later needed to read from the downloaded file to compare it against another value!