# How to download a file using the remote selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using a remote `selenium` webdriver to perform some tests. At some point, however, I need to download a file and check its contents.

I am using the remote webdriver as follows (in `python`):

```
PROXY = ...

prefs = {
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups":0,
    "download.prompt_for_download": "false",
    "download.default_directory": os.getcwd(),
}
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
  "httpProxy":PROXY,
  "ftpProxy":PROXY,
  "sslProxy":PROXY,
  "noProxy":None,
  "proxyType":"MANUAL",
  "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
  "autodetect":False
}
driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://aaa.bbb.ccc:4444/wd/hub',
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

With a 'normal' webdriver I am able to download the file without issues on the local computer. Then I can use the testing code to e.g. verify the *content* of the downloaded file (which can change depending on test parameters). It is not a test of the download itself, but I need a way to verify the *contents* of the generated file ...

But how to do that using a **remote** webdriver? I have not found anything helpful anywhere...

Comment: What's the issue u r facing? Any error log? In case your browser runs on a remote host (due to the node setup) you might want to check write permissions of the browser default download directory. Also you can set this per driver via `browser.download.dir` for FF profile and `download.default_directory` for Chrome options.

Comment: @ekostadinov: Please see updated question; I added the complete options I am using, including the download-directory options...

Comment: You want to download the file on local?

Comment: You haven't answered the question of what is the issue you are facing.

Comment: @Alex  do you have issues with automation of os native objects or  ftp automation, meaning getting the file to your execution server. Have you tried remote `webdriver` with your local?

Comment: I need to get the file to the place where it can be accessed by the test script...

Comment: I have updated the question to make my use case clearer.

Comment: @Alex  After your script is downloaded on remote server, do something like [this](https://www.eduonix.com/blog/shell-scripting/how-to-automate-ftp-transfers-in-linux-shell-scripting/) and add have it run by conjob often, which will fetch your file. Let us know if this helps

Comment: I feel like you need a share drive to store those downloaded files.

Answer (score 18):

The Selenium API doesn't provide a way to get a file downloaded on a remote machine.

But it's still possible with Selenium alone depending on the browser.

With Chrome the downloaded files can be listed by navigating `chrome://downloads/` and retrieved with an injected `<input type="file">` in the page :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import os, time, base64


def get_downloaded_files(driver):

  if not driver.current_url.startswith("chrome://downloads"):
    driver.get("chrome://downloads/")

  return driver.execute_script( \
    "return downloads.Manager.get().items_   "
    "  .filter(e => e.state === 'COMPLETE')  "
    "  .map(e => e.filePath || e.file_path); " )


def get_file_content(driver, path):

  elem = driver.execute_script( \
    "var input = window.document.createElement('INPUT'); "
    "input.setAttribute('type', 'file'); "
    "input.hidden = true; "
    "input.onchange = function (e) { e.stopPropagation() }; "
    "return window.document.documentElement.appendChild(input); " )

  elem._execute('sendKeysToElement', {'value': [ path ], 'text': path})

  result = driver.execute_async_script( \
    "var input = arguments[0], callback = arguments[1]; "
    "var reader = new FileReader(); "
    "reader.onload = function (ev) { callback(reader.result) }; "
    "reader.onerror = function (ex) { callback(ex.message) }; "
    "reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); "
    "input.remove(); "
    , elem)

  if not result.startswith('data:') :
    raise Exception("Failed to get file content: %s" % result)

  return base64.b64decode(result[result.find('base64,') + 7:])



capabilities_chrome = { \
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    # 'proxy': { \
     # 'proxyType': 'manual',
     # 'sslProxy': '50.59.162.78:8088',
     # 'httpProxy': '50.59.162.78:8088'
    # },
    'goog:chromeOptions': { \
      'args': [
      ],
      'prefs': { \
        # 'download.default_directory': "",
        # 'download.directory_upgrade': True,
        'download.prompt_for_download': False,
        'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': True,
        'safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled': False
      }
    }
  }

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities_chrome)
#driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:5555/wd/hub', capabilities_chrome)

# download a pdf file
driver.get("https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/foundation/documents")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[href$='.pdf']").click()

# list all the completed remote files (waits for at least one)
files = WebDriverWait(driver, 20, 1).until(get_downloaded_files)

# get the content of the first file remotely
content = get_file_content(driver, files[0])

# save the content in a local file in the working directory
with open(os.path.basename(files[0]), 'wb') as f:
  f.write(content)
```

With Firefox, the files can be directly listed and retrieved by calling the browser API with a script by switching the context :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import os, time, base64

def get_file_names_moz(driver):
  driver.command_executor._commands["SET_CONTEXT"] = ("POST", "/session/$sessionId/moz/context")
  driver.execute("SET_CONTEXT", {"context": "chrome"})
  return driver.execute_async_script("""
    var { Downloads } = Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm', {});
    Downloads.getList(Downloads.ALL)
      .then(list => list.getAll())
      .then(entries => entries.filter(e => e.succeeded).map(e => e.target.path))
      .then(arguments[0]);
    """)
  driver.execute("SET_CONTEXT", {"context": "content"})

def get_file_content_moz(driver, path):
  driver.execute("SET_CONTEXT", {"context": "chrome"})
  result = driver.execute_async_script("""
    var { OS } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm", {});
    OS.File.read(arguments[0]).then(function(data) {
      var base64 = Cc["@mozilla.org/scriptablebase64encoder;1"].getService(Ci.nsIScriptableBase64Encoder);
      var stream = Cc['@mozilla.org/io/arraybuffer-input-stream;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIArrayBufferInputStream);
      stream.setData(data.buffer, 0, data.length);
      return base64.encodeToString(stream, data.length);
    }).then(arguments[1]);
    """, path)
  driver.execute("SET_CONTEXT", {"context": "content"})
  return base64.b64decode(result)

capabilities_moz = { \
    'browserName': 'firefox',
    'marionette': True,
    'acceptInsecureCerts': True,
    'moz:firefoxOptions': { \
      'args': [],
      'prefs': {
        # 'network.proxy.type': 1,
        # 'network.proxy.http': '12.157.129.35', 'network.proxy.http_port': 8080,
        # 'network.proxy.ssl':  '12.157.129.35', 'network.proxy.ssl_port':  8080,      
        'browser.download.dir': '',
        'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk': 'application/octet-stream,application/pdf', 
        'browser.download.useDownloadDir': True, 
        'browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting': False, 
        'browser.download.animateNotifications': False, 
        'browser.safebrowsing.downloads.enabled': False, 
        'browser.download.folderList': 2,
        'pdfjs.disabled': True
      }
    }
  }

# launch Firefox
# driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities_moz)
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:5555/wd/hub', capabilities_moz)

# download a pdf file
driver.get("https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/foundation/documents")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[href$='.pdf']").click()

# list all the downloaded files (waits for at least one)
files = WebDriverWait(driver, 20, 1).until(get_file_names_moz)

# get the content of the last downloaded file
content = get_file_content_moz(driver, files[0])

# save the content in a local file in the working directory
with open(os.path.basename(files[0]), 'wb') as f:
  f.write(content)
```

Comment: I know how to download a file using the web driver. But this was not my question...

Comment: @Alex, your question is how to download a file with a remote instance of the driver which is exactly what I provided. In the example the file is downloaded on the remote machine and retrieved on the client machine. With the content of the file on the client side you can easily validate the file.

Comment: Sorry I misread parts of your answer. But in my case I also need to set a proxy in those desiredCapabilities. Currently the setup is something like: `PROXY = "some.proxy.ch:80"

    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
      "httpProxy":PROXY,
      "ftpProxy":PROXY,
      "sslProxy":PROXY,
      "noProxy":None,
      "proxyType":"MANUAL",
      "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
      "autodetect":False
    } `Will this work with your suggested solution?

Comment: It seems you have forgotten this extremely important fact in your answer.

Comment: @Alex, it should work with Firefox. For Chrome it will depend on whether the proxy overrides the local file scheme (`file:///`).

Comment: But where to define the proxy settings in your Firefox solution?

Comment: @Alex, just like in your example, add the `proxy` entry to the capabilities. You may also need to set the  `noProxy: '127.0.0.1,localhost'` to make it work with Chrome.

Comment: Looks like Firefox is not running in the remote host location. I will try to do it with chrome in instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158516/discussion-between-alex-and-florent-b).

Comment: Ok, I ran the example and got a timeout error in the line `files = WebDriverWait(driver, 20, 1).until(get_file_list_cr)`

Comment: The timeout indicates that there's no file successfully downloads in the page. I'll try latter with a proxy and I'll get back to you. It seems that there's also an issue with Firefox where `options.to_capabilities` returns the options instead of the capabilities.

Comment: @Alex, I tested the code with a proxy and it's working with both Chrome and Firefox. Note that with Firefox inferior to version 58, you'll have to use the preferences to set the proxy.

Comment: That is nice for you, but for me its not working. I get the timeout error as indicated above. So what else to do? How to further invest this problem? How to debug it further...?

Comment: @Alex, It could be that the download was specifically disabled on the remote platform. Take a screenshot of `chrome://downloads/` or remote desktop to investigate the reason. Make sure that the latest drivers are used. You could also try to set a download director matching a temporary folder on the remote machine in case the default folder has not write permissions.

Comment: @FlorentB. The link you shared seems to point to dotnet version of selenium. As far as the implementation in Java is concerned, there is no setContext method.

Comment: @Savvy, my bad the command is not implemented in the Java client. Have a look at [Take full page screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201692/2887618) for an example on how to call a command.

Comment: @Savvy, I found another solution to retrieve the file remotely with Chrome. Please delete the comments that are no longer relevant if it works for you.

Comment: @FlorentB. I know its been a while since I could finally come around to testing your solution; sorry about that. Just wanted to thank you and let you know its now working for both Firefox and Chrome. I have added my implementation in Java to help others that may find themselves in the same situation I was.

Comment: @FlorentB. It looks like it's not working anymore

Answer (score 6):

#### Webdriver:

If you are using webdriver, means your code uses the internal Selenium client and server code to communicate with browser instance. And the downloaded files are stored in the local machine which can be directly accessed by using languages like java, python, .Net, node.js, ...

#### Remote WebDriver [Selenium-Grid]:

If you are using Remote webdriver means you are using GRID concept, The main purpose of the Gird is `To distribute your tests over multiple machines or virtual machines (VMs)`. Form this your code uses Selenium client to communicate with Selenium Grid Server, which passes instruction to the Registered node with the specified browser. Form their Grid Node will pass the instructions form browser-specific driver to browser instance. **Here the downloads takes place to the `file-system | hard-disk` of that system, but users don't have access to the file-system on the virtual machines where the browser is running.**

> - By using javascript if we can access the file, then we can [convert the file to base64-String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36280818/5081877) and return to the client code. But for security reasons Javascript will not allow to read files form Disk.
> - If Selenium Grid hub and node's are in same system, and they are in public Network then you may change the path of the downloaded file to Some of the public downloaded paths like `../Tomcat/webapps/Root/CutrentTimeFolder/file.pdf`. By using the public URL you can access the file directly.

For example downloading the file[] from Root folder of tomcat.

```java
System.out.println("FireFox Driver Path « "+ geckodriverCloudRootPath);
File temp = File.createTempFile("geckodriver",  null);
temp.setExecutable(true);
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL( geckodriverCloudRootPath ), temp);

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", temp.getAbsolutePath() );
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
```

> - If Selenium Grid hub and node are **not in same system**, the you may not get the downloaded file, because Grid Hub will be in public network`[WAN]` and Node will in private network`[LAN]` of the organisation.

You can change browser's downloading files path to a specified folder on hard disk. By using the below code.

```java
String downloadFilepath = "E:\\download";
    
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("--test-type");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); //to disable browser extension popup

DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

@ See

- [Downloading Files to a Sauce Labs Virtual Machine Prior to Testing](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Downloading+Files+to+a+Sauce+Labs+Virtual+Machine+Prior+to+Testing)
- [Testing PDF Downloads](https://support.saucelabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005860628-Testing-PDF-Downloads)
- [Grid HUB Running as a standalone server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39640250/5081877)

Answer (score 6):

@FlorentB's answer for Chrome works up until Chrome version 79. For newer versions, the function `get_downloaded_files` needed to be updated as the `downloads.Manager` is not accessible anymore. However, this updated version should work with previous versions as well.

```
def get_downloaded_files(driver):

  if not driver.current_url.startswith("chrome://downloads"):
    driver.get("chrome://downloads/")

  return driver.execute_script( \
     "return  document.querySelector('downloads-manager')  "
     " .shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList')         "
     " .items.filter(e => e.state === 'COMPLETE')          "
     " .map(e => e.filePath || e.file_path || e.fileUrl || e.file_url); ")
```

Comment: For anyone doing this Dec 2023 onwards, you need to replace `e.state === 'COMPLETE'` with `e.state === 2`. Thanks for the pointless change Chrome team.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the Java version of @Florent 's answer above. With a lot of guidance from him and some digging and tweaking I was finally able to get it to work for Java. I figured I could save other people some time by laying it out here.

**Firefox**

First we need to create a custom firefox driver because we need to use the SET_CONTEXT command which is not implemented in the Java client(as of selenium - 3.141.59)

```
public class CustomFirefoxDriver extends RemoteWebDriver{


    public CustomFirefoxDriver(URL RemoteWebDriverUrl, FirefoxOptions options) throws Exception {
        super(RemoteWebDriverUrl, options);
        CommandInfo cmd = new CommandInfo("/session/:sessionId/moz/context", HttpMethod.POST);
        Method defineCommand = HttpCommandExecutor.class.getDeclaredMethod("defineCommand", String.class, CommandInfo.class);
        defineCommand.setAccessible(true);
        defineCommand.invoke(super.getCommandExecutor(), "SET_CONTEXT", cmd);
    }


    public Object setContext(String context) {
        return execute("SET_CONTEXT", ImmutableMap.of("context", context)).getValue();
    }
}
```

The code below retrieves the content of a downloaded .xls file and saves it as a file(temp.xls) in the same directory where the Java class is run. In Firefox this is fairly straightforward as we can use the browser API

```
public String getDownloadedFileNameBySubStringFirefox(String Matcher) {

    String fileName = "";

    ((CustomFirefoxDriver) driver).setContext("chrome");

    String script = "var { Downloads } = Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm', {});"
            + "Downloads.getList(Downloads.ALL).then(list => list.getAll())"
            + ".then(entries => entries.filter(e => e.succeeded).map(e => e.target.path))"
            + ".then(arguments[0]);";

    String fileNameList = js.executeAsyncScript(script).toString();
    String name = fileNameList.substring(1, fileNameList.length() -1);

    if(name.contains(Matcher)) {
        fileName = name;
    }

    ((CustomFirefoxDriver) driver).setContext("content");

    return fileName;
}

public void getDownloadedFileContentFirefox(String fileIdentifier) {

    String filePath = getDownloadedFileNameBySubStringFirefox(fileIdentifier);
    ((CustomFirefoxDriver) driver).setContext("chrome");

    String script = "var { OS } = Cu.import(\"resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm\", {});" + 
                    "OS.File.read(arguments[0]).then(function(data) {" + 
                    "var base64 = Cc[\"@mozilla.org/scriptablebase64encoder;1\"].getService(Ci.nsIScriptableBase64Encoder);" +
                    "var stream = Cc['@mozilla.org/io/arraybuffer-input-stream;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIArrayBufferInputStream);" +
                    "stream.setData(data.buffer, 0, data.length);" +
                    "return base64.encodeToString(stream, data.length);" +
                    "}).then(arguments[1]);" ;

    Object base64FileContent = js.executeAsyncScript(script, filePath);//.toString();
    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get("temp.xls"), DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64FileContent.toString()));
    } catch (IOException i) {
        System.out.println(i.getMessage());
    }

}
```

**Chrome**

We need to employ a different approach to achieve the same goal in Chrome. We append an input file element to the Downloads page and pass the file location to this element. Once this element points to our required file, we use it to read its content.

```
public String getDownloadedFileNameBySubStringChrome(String Matcher) {
    String file = "";
    //The script below returns the list of files as a list of the form '[$FileName1, $FileName2...]'
    // with the most recently downloaded file listed first.
    String script = "return downloads.Manager.get().items_.filter(e => e.state === 'COMPLETE').map(e => e.file_url);" ;
    if(!driver.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("chrome://downloads/")) {
        driver.get("chrome://downloads/");
        }
    String fileNameList =  js.executeScript(script).toString();
    //Removing square brackets
    fileNameList = fileNameList.substring(1, fileNameList.length() -1);
    String [] fileNames = fileNameList.split(",");
    for(int i=0; i<fileNames.length; i++) {
        if(fileNames[i].trim().contains(Matcher)) {
            file = fileNames[i].trim();
            break;
        }
    }

    return file;

}


public void getDownloadedFileContentChrome(String fileIdentifier) {

    //This causes the user to be navigated to the Chrome Downloads page
    String fileName = getDownloadedFileNameBySubStringChrome(fileIdentifier);
    //Remove "file://" from the file path
    fileName = fileName.substring(7);

    String script =  "var input = window.document.createElement('INPUT'); " +
            "input.setAttribute('type', 'file'); " +
            "input.setAttribute('id', 'downloadedFileContent'); " +
            "input.hidden = true; " +
            "input.onchange = function (e) { e.stopPropagation() }; " +
            "return window.document.documentElement.appendChild(input); " ;
    WebElement fileContent = (WebElement) js.executeScript(script);
    fileContent.sendKeys(fileName);

    String asyncScript = "var input = arguments[0], callback = arguments[1]; " +
            "var reader = new FileReader(); " +
            "reader.onload = function (ev) { callback(reader.result) }; " +
            "reader.onerror = function (ex) { callback(ex.message) }; " +
            "reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); " +
            "input.remove(); " ;

    String content = js.executeAsyncScript(asyncScript, fileContent).toString();
    int fromIndex = content.indexOf("base64,") +7 ;
    content = content.substring(fromIndex);

    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get("temp.xls"), DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(content));
    } catch (IOException i) {
        System.out.println(i.getMessage());
    }

}
```

The reason I needed this setup was because my test suite was running on a Jenkin's server; and the Selenium Grid hub and Node set up it was pointing to was running in Docker containers(https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) on a different server. Once again, this is just a Java translation of @Florent 's answer above. Please refer it for more info.

Comment: Where is the `js` object coming from?

Comment: I found it `IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;`

Answer (score 1):

I found this article on Medium. It references another tutorial that may help.

https://lindajosiah.medium.com/python-selenium-docker-downloading-and-saving-files-ebb9ab8b2039

I am using a docker image for the python download script and a docker stack for the selenium hub.

Source:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/docker-compose-v2.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.8.1-20230306
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
    ports:
      - "6900:5900"
    networks:
      - scraper-service
    volumes:
      - ./downloads:/home/seluser/Downloads // <= link a local directory to the downloads location
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.8.1-20230306
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
    networks:
      - scraper-service
networks:
  scraper-service:
    external: true
```

And then I get set the download directory in my python script.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": "/home/seluser/Downloads/", // <= link to the downloads location
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": False
})
chrome = webdriver.Remote(
      command_executor='http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub',
      options=options)
```

You can really set any external volume you want.

Comment: Consider volume permission of the container and the host or other containers. Selenium is using a certain userid and groupid. By fixing that this solution works with Compose. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This works for PHP php-webdriver in 2020 for Chrome:

```
$downloaddir = "/tmp/";
$host = 'http://ipaddress:4444/wd/hub';
try {
    $options = new ChromeOptions();
    $options->setExperimentalOption("prefs",["safebrowsing.enabled" => "true", "download.default_directory" => $downloaddir]);
    $options->addArguments( array("disable-extensions",'safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist','safebrowsing-disable-download-protection') );
    $caps = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
    $caps->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
    $caps->setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour","accept");
    $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $caps);
    $driver->manage()->window()->setPosition(new WebDriverPoint(500,0));
    $driver->manage()->window()->setSize(new WebDriverDimension(1280,1000));
    $driver->get("https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-rtf-download/");
    sleep(1);
    $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("//table//tr//td[contains(., 'rtf')]//ancestor::tr[1]//a"))->click();
    sleep(1);
    $driver->get('chrome://downloads/');
    sleep(1);
    // $inject = "return downloads.Manager.get().items_.filter(e => e.state === 'COMPLETE').map(e => e.filePath || e.file_path); ";
    $inject = "return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('a').innerText;";
    $filename = $driver->executeScript(" $inject" );
    echo "File name: $filename<br>";
    $driver->executeScript( 
        "var input = window.document.createElement('INPUT'); ".
        "input.setAttribute('type', 'file'); ".
        "input.hidden = true; ".
        "input.onchange = function (e) { e.stopPropagation() }; ".
        "return window.document.documentElement.appendChild(input); " );
    $elem1 = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
    $elem1->sendKeys($downloaddir.$filename);
    $result = $driver->executeAsyncScript( 
        "var input = arguments[0], callback = arguments[1]; ".
        "var reader = new FileReader(); ".
        "reader.onload = function (ev) { callback(reader.result) }; ".
        "reader.onerror = function (ex) { callback(ex.message) }; ".
        "reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); ".
        "input.remove(); "
        , [$elem1]);
    $coding = 'base64,';
    $cstart = strpos( $result, 'base64,' );
    if ( $cstart !== false ) 
        $result = base64_decode(substr( $result, $cstart + strlen($coding) ));
    echo "File content: <br>$result<br>";
    $driver->quit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _how_ it solves the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason (pylint) you would like to avoid accessing a protected member (elem._execute), then the line:

```
elem._execute('sendKeysToElement', {'value': [ path ], 'text': path})
```

in @FlorentB's answer can be rewritten as:

```
elem.parent.execute('sendKeysToElement', {'value': [ path ], 'text': path, 'id': elem.id})
```

Source: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in line 703, 708, and 727