# Is there any way to read a csv file downloaded in a GRID machine (Selenium-Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a download functionality in my website, it will download a csv file. My moto is to check the content of the file.

My java code to read the download file is woking fine if i download it in the local machine (Where code and application run in same machine), but the problem with my code is when the download item is present in some other machine (GRID)

I want to read the file from the GRID machine, but the code might be running in my local machine or some other server(e.g. Jenkins).
(Download of file is optional. If we can read the content without download also, its fine for me)

Comment: If you know the path of the file just download directly example in java https://stackabuse.com/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-java/

Comment: Its not in local server.. It will get downloaded in some remote server.

Comment: As you mentioned download is optional above is the option to directly download on the server machine irrespective of node . If you want to download file on node machine and access on hub machine/server machine then it wont be easy.

Comment: Is there any way to transfer the file from GRID machine to some other machine?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47155388/5324105 Check this if it helps