# Enable downloads in headless chrome with Selenium Grid

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

The only way that I've found to enable downloads in Headless Chrome is with the following code:

```
 var param = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 param.Add("behavior", "allow");
 param.Add("downloadPath", $"C:\\Users\\{Environment.UserName}\\Downloads\\");
 driver.ExecuteChromeCommand("Page.setDownloadBehavior", param);
```

However, when using Selenium Grid, the driver must be initialized as `RemoteWebDriver`:

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(url), options);
```

`RemoteWebDriver` doesn't have the `ExecuteChromeCommand` method and it can't be cast to `ChromeDriver` (`(ChromeDriver)driver` throws an exception).

Therefore, how can I enable downloads in headless chrome when using Selenium Grid?

Comment: This answer might point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068912/how-to-download-a-file-using-the-remote-selenium-webdriver