# Remote File Downloads

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

**Background**: Working on some file download tests with Protractor and Chrome. I run on a selenium grid, so the tests and my Node env are executing on a server (e.g. `8.2.2.2`) while the file downloads are on a remote windows machine (e.g. `14.3.3.3`).

The file download used to be stored on the same server that also kicked off the tests, so I was just waiting for a file to exist before performing my assertion:

```
browser.wait(() => {
    return fs.existsSync(filePath)
}).then(() => {
    // expect something
})
```

**Problem:** Now, the files dont write to the Server (they download directly to the browser) so I have nothing to grab... so far.  Since I use a selenium grid  I can't directly read the remote machine from the test server.

**Question:** Will the protractor browser object or chromedriver have any information about that file download that I can grab?  Trying to find a way to access both file name and file size?  I'm digging into the browser object but havent found anything yet.

Comment: Navigate `chrome://downloads/` to get a list of all the downloaded files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068912/how-to-download-a-file-using-the-remote-selenium-webdriver/47164044#47164044

Comment: @FlorentB. Awesome thanks, I've got a working version now off that.  Not sure how I didnt come across that question in my previous searches

Comment: @FlorentB. Where do you find docs on these methods? `downloads.Manager` etc.  Didnt even know those existed

Comment: these methods are undocumented. You can find them by inspecting the source of `chrome://downloads/` with devtools. You can also find them in the source of chromium: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/resources/md_downloads/manager.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot this was never answered, so I'll post my own solution after @Florent B helped me in the comments.  I broke this down for simplicity sake, the code could be much cleaner (also depends on your use case):

```
it('generates a file', () => {
    // begin file download
    btnGenerateReport.click()
    .then(() => {
        // open a new window to leave current one in state
        return browser.executeScript('window.open()')
    })
    .then(() => {
        // switch to new window
        return browser.getAllWindowHandles().then((handles) => {
            return browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
        })
    })
    .then(() => {
        // navigate to downloads
        return browser.get('chrome://downloads')
    })
    .then(() => {
        // pauses tests until download has 1 item AND item status is 'Complete'
        return browser.wait(() => {
            return browser.executeScript('return downloads.Manager.get().items_.length > 0 && downloads.Manager.get().items_[0].state === "COMPLETE"');
        }, 600000, `"downloads.Manager.get().items_" did not have length > 0 and/or item[0].state did not === "COMPLETE" within ${600000/1000} seconds`)
    })
    .then(() => {
        // get downloads
        return browser.executeScript('return downloads.Manager.get().items_');
    }).then((items) => {
        // this is your download item(s)
        console.log(items);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I am able to use this. This is not working in headless browser. Any inputs to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

To assert downloading files in remote using protractor/selenium:

1. Create a FTP server manually on your remote to host the download folder
2. Set capabilities for download without prompt to that particular folder(hosted via FTP) in protractor

   ```js
   capabilities: {
       browserName: "chrome",
       chromeOptions: {
           args: ["--disable-gpu"],
           prefs: {
               download: {
                   prompt_for_download: false,
                   directory_upgrade: true,
                   default_directory: `${__dirname}\\src\\json.file\\`
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Assert the content of the folder using any ftp module in node

```js
npm install ftp-client
```