# Chrome args and prefs don't seems to be work in protractor conf

Tags: google-chrome, testing, selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Need help with below issues. I have work around for issue 1 so any tips on issue 2 would be great:

1. `--start-maximized` won't trigger full window so my current work around is adding below line in `beforeEach` function:

   ```
   browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
   ```
2. Trying to download file to default directory but the file is just going to download folder on my C drive instead of /tmp/downloads (on another drive).

My config:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOption': {
        args: ['--lang=en', '--start-maximized'],
        prefs: {
            'download': {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'default_directory': '/tmp/downloads',
            },

        },

    },
},
```

As for download, I'm currently using solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935696/protractor-e2e-test-case-for-downloading-pdf-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo. It should be [`chromeOptions`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#adding-chrome-specific-options), not `chromeOption`.

Comment: omg @alecxe, I must be so blind :) . Prompt_for_download is still appearing and I will google a bit more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the options in protractor conf have been updated to be without `"--"`.

So perhaps try without `"--"`?

`args: ['lang=en', 'start-maximized']`