# Protractor: Steps execute not one by one

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, download, protractor

Why the Protractor do steps not one by one?

The code example:

```
browser.get('http://mywebpage.com');
element(by.css('[ng-click="fileCtrl.saveFile()"]')).click();
var today = new Date();
var todayPlus = new Date();
while(todayPlus.valueOf()<today.valueOf()+7000){
     todayPlus = new Date();
}
browser.driver.sleep(2000);
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var c = fs.exists('C:\\Users\\volodymyr.nabok\\Downloads\\file.txt', function(ex){ util.debug(ex ? "Yes." : "No-p"); });
```

In my case the Protractor firstly check if the 'file.txt' exists then download it. As you see I tried to freeze script for 7 seconds and freeze the browser for 2 seconds but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it takes time for a file to be downloaded. You can approach it with hardcoded wait intervals, but a more reliable approach would be to *wait until the file is downloaded using `browser.wait()`*, see this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27031924/771848).

Comment: Seems it help. Thank you.
Interesting that yesterday the same solution did not work (Protractor said something like: "Error: Wait timed out after 3000 ms"). Anyway, now it is working. Thanks once more.