# E2E test with internet explorer where I need to download a file

Tags: internet-explorer, protractor, profile

How to create the profile for Internet explorer in protractor for automatic download files.

I found for Chrome and Firefox but I could not find it for internet explorer

Reference: [Protractor e2e test case for downloading pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935696/protractor-e2e-test-case-for-downloading-pdf-file)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this doesn't answer your question directly, [here](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/) is a link to an excellent blog about "How to download files with selenium and why you should not". Author talks about different use cases and provides a back door solution to do this in Java. The most critical question the article mentions is

> "What are you going to do with this downloaded file?"
>
> "Do you want to just makes sure that you get 200 OK from the server?"
>
> "Do you want to verify the content?"

Obviously mostly people would say "yes" to "200 OK verification", If you want to validate the content of lets a PDF document, then its outside the scope of selenium anyways. The [article](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/) provides Java solution to check if you get 200 OK from the server, Since you are using protractor, I'll provide a nodejs solution.

```
var request = require('request');
var fileDownloadElement = element(by.css('#download'));
fileDownloadElement.getAttribute('href').then(function(url) {
    request(url,function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
          throw new Error('Error downloading file', error);
        }
        if(response.statusCode !== 200) {
           throw new Error('Server threw non 200 OK status ->', response.statusCode);
        }
        if(!body) {
            throw new Error('Server did not respond with any data');
        } else {
           //write body to a file if you want to do anything with it
        }
    });
});
```

I used [request](https://github.com/request/request) client up here, you can use it or any other similar client.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code, but hope you get the idea.