# How to check if file has been downloaded with Protractor/Selenium?

Tags: selenium, protractor

Configuration:

```
 capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {

            prefs: {
                download: {
                    'prompt_for_download': false,
                    'directory_upgrade': true,
                    'default_directory':  'src/test/javascript/e2e/downloads'
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

I download with this

```
productDashboardPageObject.exportDashboard();
```

It downloads but I cant check if it was downloaded.

How to check if files has been downloaded ?

Comment: You can add a wait for the file existence similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27031924/771848.

Comment: but there they give specific file name var filename = '/tmp/export.csv'; . mine is random

Comment: Well, you can use the directory watcher like [this one](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher).

Comment: sorry, i couldnot see. can you give an example as an answer please @alecxe