# Checking if File Was Downloaded on Windows With Protractor

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I am trying to run a test where a file gets downloaded from our web application. The problem that I am running into however is that the file already exists and I have an `if` statement to handle it and delete it prior to downloading another one. The problem is though that it never goes into the `if` statement.

I know that my file path is correct. Is there something else I am doing wrong here?

```js
    const fs = require('fs')
    fit('Download Visible Records', () => {
        const filename = `C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\DataExport_2017-04-18-10-04am.csv`
        if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
            console.log('Are we getting here??') // NEVER ACTUALLY GETS HERE EVEN THOUGH THE FILE DOES EXIST
            // Make sure the browser doesn't have to rename the download
            fs.unlink(filename)
            console.log('how about here?')
        }
        claims.downloadVizRecords()
        browser.driver.wait(() => {
            expect(fs.existsSync(filename)).toBe(true)
        }, 10000)
    })
```

Comment: I created my file download test awhile ago, so I can't remember how I reached this conclusion, but I have an extra parameter in my `existsSync` function.  `fs.existsSync('filepath', fs.R_OK);`, which according to fs docs is a "Flag indicating that the file can be read by the calling process."  Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @Gunderson Thank you very much for the suggestion, however that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @Gunderson So it appears that my process running the test. I am running from gulp on a mac to a windows machine, does not have read/write access to the file. Even after changing the permissions for the directory to be Everyone has full access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor e2e test case for downloading pdf file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935696/protractor-e2e-test-case-for-downloading-pdf-file)

Answer (score 0):

My code works fine:

```
if (fs.existsSync('D:/CI/script/result/Report.html')) {
   fs.unlinkSync('D:/CI/script/result/Report.html');
}
```