# Angular 6 - When testing file download with Protractor, how do I set a relative path for the file's destination

Tags: angular, protractor

I need to download a CSV and check its content in a Protractor test.  The tests are running as part of our deployment process, so the path of this download needs to be relative.

Looking at other [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26127745/4059156), I have created a folder at /e2e called download and added this to my `protractor.conf.js`:

```
capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      chromeOptions: {
          args: ['--disable-gpu']
      },
      prefs: {
        'download': {
          'prompt_for_download': false,
          'default_directory': '/e2e/download'
        }
      }
    },
```

Here is the original test, which is clicking on a button to download the file and then checking the contents in my local Downloads folder (this needs to be changed once the download itself is actually working).

```
  it('should export the csv', () => {
    const filename = '../../../Downloads/new_Name_List_members.csv';
    const exportButton = testUI.findElementBy({findBy: 'buttonText', value: 'Export to CSV'});
    exportButton.click().then(() => {
      browser.driver.wait(function() {
        // Wait until the file has been downloaded.
        return fs.existsSync(filename);
      }, 5000).then(function() {
        expect(fs.readFileSync(filename, { encoding: 'utf8' })).toContain('username,email,name');
      });
    });
  });
```

Even though I've specified the path in `capabilities.prefs`, the file is still downloading to my local Downloads folder when the button is clicked.  Even if I set this to the full path---`'default_directory': '/Users/kkanya/Documents/Code/project/e2e/download'`---it still downloads to my local Downloads.

I've looked through the protractor [config.ts file](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts) and can't spot anything that might allow me to change the default download directory.  In fact, I don't see a `prefs`, which leads me to believe this may not be the correct way to do it with the newest Protractor.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I came up with.  It seems to be working.  It first deletes the `download` directory in `e2e` and then recreates it at the time the file is downloaded.

Note that `prefs` is a value on `chromeOptions` (I had this incorrect in my original question.)

`protractor.conf.js`:

```
exports.config = {
    capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--disable-gpu'],
        prefs: {
          download: {
            'prompt_for_download': false,
            'default_directory': './e2e/download'
          }
        }
      }
    },

    ...

    onPrepare() {
      // delete ./e2e/download before tests are run
        rmDir('./e2e/download');
    }

// https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/how-to-clear-a-directory-before-running-protractor-tests/27653
var fs = require('fs');  

function rmDir (dirPath) {
  try { var files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath); }
  catch(e) { return; }
  if (files.length > 0)
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var filePath = dirPath + '/' + files[i];
      if (fs.statSync(filePath).isFile())
        fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
      else
        rmDir(filePath);
    }
  fs.rmdirSync(dirPath);
};
```

the `.spec.ts` file:

```
  it('should export the csv', () => {
    const filename = './e2e/download/new_Name_List_members.csv';

    const exportButton = testUI.findElementBy({findBy: 'buttonText', value: 'Export to CSV'});
    exportButton.click().then(() => {
      browser.driver.wait(function() {
        // Wait until the file has been downloaded.
        return fs.existsSync(filename);
      }, 5000).then(function() {
        expect(fs.readFileSync(filename, { encoding: 'utf8' })).toContain('username,email,name');
      });
    });
  });
```

Hope this helps someone.